# NSWindowController–Get notified before window is shown?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I have a window contained in a nib file that gets loaded by a custom subclass of `NSWindowController` like this:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow"];

    return self;
}
```

I'd like to initialize the views in this window before it becomes visible. Right now I'm reading some User Defaults and setting the window's views in `windowDidLoad`. But unfortunately, the newly initialized values are applied only after the window has become visible, resulting in the uninitialized values flashing very briefly.

`windowWillLoad` doesn't work as the window has not been loaded from the nib file yet at that point.

How can I initialize the window before it is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- (void)awakeFromNib` is a very good place to do view setup. It is called after all objects have been de-archived and outlets have been connected.

More info [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Normally, I use this method to do such kind of setup, but I thought it wouldn't work in this case, as I didn't instantiate this window controller in the nib file, but rather in code, in the action method that's called when a certain menu item is clicked. However, I just tried it and it works, even though the window controller isn't unarchived from a nib file, but instantiated programmatically. How come this works?

Comment: Since you are calling `initWithWindowNibName:`, self becomes the owner of the nib and `awakeFromNib` is called when loaded. Beware of the side effect: the nib loading will probably be deferred until the window is shown. To really know who calls the method, put a breakpoint in `awakeFromNib` and look at the backtrace.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm fine with the deferred loading being deferred—after all, I'm only using `awakeFromNib` to initialize the UI of the very window contained in that nib.

Comment: A look in the debugger, as you suggested, shows that the nib is indeed loaded only after I call the window controller's `showWindow:` method, whereupon `awakeFromNib` is called.

Comment: Btw, should I call `[super awakeFromNib]` in the window controller's `awakeFromNib` method? Should I pass `self` or `nil` to `showWindow:` as the sender when calling it directly in code (i.e. not as the action of a control)?

Comment: You do not need to call `[super awakeFromNib]` in most cases (see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) about that). I usually pass `nil` as argument for `showWindow:` when calling it programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

You could do your own ["`showWindow`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindowController/showWindow%3a) method.

```
- (IBAction)showWindow:(id)sender
{
    // do whatever initialization 
    // or window UI setup you 
    // need to do right here
    [super showWindow: sender];
}
```